# How to use XML in C# file instead of using external XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file, currently external to the C# code and it is loaded like this:

```
var xElem = XElement.Load("ProductTable.xml");
```

How do I "use" this file as an "embedded" element in my C# code instead of having it as an external file?

I know I am not clear enough with the words "use" and "embedded". What I want to do is to use it as some kind of variable such as

```
var myXML = /* content of the XML file here */;
```

**just so that I don't have to use an external xml file**. Thanks.

Comment: So you basically just want the xml content of the file assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a resources file in your project. Just dragNdrop it there and you will be able to access it.
Another way is to add this file to project, then click properties, set compile method to emedded and then do smth like this

```
try
   {
      _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      _imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyImage.bmp");
      _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyXmlFile.xml"));
   }
   catch
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the XML file to your project.  Set its build setting (in properties via Solution Explorer) to Embedded Resource.  Then you can use something like...

```
 var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.ProductTable.xml")))
 { /* ... */ }
```

You'll probably want to use the XmlReader or whatever they call it these days.

Derived from [How to embed and access...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) from MSDN.